# Stop a Mac from sleeping while a bash script is running, then allow it to sleep as normal once complete

Tags: mac, bash, sleep, rsync

I've got my Mac to wake up during the night and run an rsync to back it up. This is configured through Energy Saver > Schedule.

However it seems that it's going back to sleep before it can get anything done, so I need to stop it sleeping during the execution of the bash script that rsync runs from.

I figured the best way (if it's possible) is to issue a command to set the sleep timeout to "Never" or a very long timeout before it rsyncs and then back to normal once it's complete. Is there a better solution for doing this?

Answer (score 23):

## Caffeinate

For example:

```
caffeinate -i rsync -avz someuser@somehost:somefolder /some/local/folder
```

From the man page:

```
EXAMPLE
     caffeinate -i make
        caffeinate forks a process, execs "make" in it, and holds an
        assertion that prevents idle sleep as long as that process
        is running.
```

See `man caffeinate` for details.

Comment: So for a .sh script it would be "caffeinate -i ./myscript.sh" ?

Answer (score 11):

## Mac OS X 10.8 (Mountain Lion) and later

Use the `caffeinate` command. See [Nathan Long's answer](https://superuser.com/a/807193/21562) or `man caffeinate` for details.

## Mac OS X 10.7 (Lion) and earlier

It's buried in the manual page, but **pmset** has a very simple mode for preventing sleep. If you execute the command `pmset noidle` your Mac will be kept awake until that process is killed. Here is how to use it in a script:

```
# launch process to prevent sleep and move it to the background
pmset noidle &
# save the process ID
PMSETPID=$!

... do stuff here ...
... don't fall asleep ...
... watch out for that tree!
... ok we're free and clear now ...

# kill pmset so the computer can sleep if it wants to
kill $PMSETPID
```

This is better than using pmset to change your sleep settings, which requires root access and (assuming you want to be a good citizen) some way of detecting the current settings and changing them back when you're done.

Comment: `pmset noidle` is deprecated: the man page says: `This argument is deprecated in favor of caffeinate(8)`. See my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
man pmset
```

:-)